# How to use a FloatingActionButton in flutter to perform action on current pageview page?

Tags: flutter

I'm pretty new to flutter, but learning a lot from youtube and google, and even chatGPT.   One thing I haven't been able to figure out though, is how to use a floatingactionbutton (FAB) on the current page of a page view.

Lets say one of the pages in my pageview looks like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ModelsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ModelsPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _State();
  }
}

class _State extends State<ModelsPage> {
  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
        shadowColor: Colors.black,
        foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.foregroundColor,
        title: const Text('Models Page'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add_to_photos),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Text('Models count $count',
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.amber,
                fontSize: 20,
              ))),
      
    );
  }
}
```

And the relevant part of my main page is this:

```
 body: PageView(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: controller,
              children: pagesList,
              onPageChanged: (index) {
                pageChanged(index);
              },
            ),
            floatingActionButtonLocation:
                FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
              splashColor: Colors.amberAccent,
              //elevation: 2,
              onPressed: () {
                double? currentPage = controller.page;
                String pagenum = currentPage.toString();
                print('Current Page: $pagenum');
              },
              tooltip: 'Increment',
              shape: CircleBorder(),
              child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.black),
            ),
```

the "children" for the page view are:

```
final Map<int, Widget> pagesMap = {
    0: const HomePage(),
    1: const ModelsPage(),
    3: const StudiosPage(),
    4: const ShootsPage(),
  };
```

I have a working bottom navigation bar/app bar that allows me to switch between the pages, and I added print statements that tell me I'm on page 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.    However once the page is loaded, I can't figure out how to get the FAB to do something on the page, in this case, even incrementing the "Models Count: 0" by one would suffice to figure it out.   I know that when it's a single page, doing something like

```
onTap: () => setState(() => count++
```

is enough to do it, but how do you interact with other pages that have been loaded into the pageview?   On most pages, I'm probably going to have the FAB just create a new item that'll get saved in a database and added to a listview, but I just don't know where to start on finding out how to interact with the widgets on the displayed page in the pageview.

Here's a current view of the 2nd page:
[image]

and here's the home page that has a listview.
[image]

in this example, maybe on page 0 (home) I want the FAB to add a new item to the list view, on page 1 (Models) I want it to increment the counter by 1 when I press it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

i think you can do 2 thinks, pass arguments to the PagesConstructors, this arguments can be variables on your models page, and change when the fab, and when you change, rebuild the pages of the pagebuilder, other solutions is a state management, such a Provider package, with this you can create a singleton that is on top level of the app, and can access from every page, and if is a change on its values the page rebuild, is very simple with a short video of 'flutter provider' in YouTube you will do in a moment.

Good luck.